# PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR draws black on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I want to implement eraser in my paint app. But the code

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

draws black line on canvas. If I am changing the background color the canvas draws black on it too.

I have also tried using setLayerType() but it draws white on any color background.

```
// In constructor
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Below is the code for my PaintView.

```
public class PaintView extends View {
    private Bitmap bitmapBackground,bitmapView;
    private int backgroundColor;
    private int brushSize;
    private int eraserSize;
    private float mX,mY;
    private Canvas canvas=null;
    private final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE=4;
    private int paintColor;

    private int modeStatus;
    /*
    1 for brush
    2 for eraser
    */
    
    private ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    private int historyPointer=0;

    public PaintView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise() {
        eraserSize=12;
        brushSize=12;
        backgroundColor= Color.WHITE;
        paintColor = Color.BLACK;
        modeStatus = 1;

        paints.add(createPaint());
        paths.add(new Path());
        historyPointer++;
    }

    private float toPx(int brushSize) {
        return brushSize*(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public void init(int width,int height) {
        bitmapBackground=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapView=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas=new Canvas(bitmapView);
    }

   
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBackground,0,0,null);

        for (int i=0;i<historyPointer;i++) {
            Path path = paths.get(i);
            Paint paint = paints.get(i);

            canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        }

    }

    private Paint createPaint() {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(paintColor);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        if (modeStatus==1) {
            paint.setXfermode(null);
            paint.setShader(null);
            paint.setMaskFilter(null);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(toPx(brushSize));
        }
        else {
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(toPx(eraserSize));
        }

        return paint;
    }

    private Path createPath(float x,float y) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x,y);
        return path;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor=backgroundColor;
        invalidate(); //Redraw
    }

    public void setBrushSize(int brushSize) {
        this.brushSize=brushSize;
        modeStatus=1;
    }

    public void setBrushColor(int color) {
        paintColor=color;
    }

    public void setEraserSize(int eraserSize) {
        this.eraserSize=eraserSize;
        modeStatus=2;
    }

    public int getBrushSize() {
        return this.brushSize;
    }

    public int getEraserSize() {
        return this.eraserSize;
    }

    private void updateHistory(Path path) {
        if (historyPointer==paths.size()) {
            paths.add(path);
            paints.add(createPaint());
            historyPointer++;
        }
        else {
            // For undo and redo
            paths.set(historyPointer,path);
            paints.set(historyPointer,createPaint());
            historyPointer++;

            for (int i=historyPointer,size=paths.size();i<size;i++) {
                paths.remove(historyPointer);
                paints.remove(historyPointer);
            }
        }
    }

    private Path getCurrentPath() {
        return paths.get(historyPointer-1);
    }

    private Paint getCurrentPaint() {
        return paints.get(historyPointer-1);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            // Case when finger touches the screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x,y);
                break;

            // Case when finger moves on screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x,y);
                break;

            // Case when finger is taken away from screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                break;

            default :
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mX=x;
        mY=y;
        updateHistory(createPath(x,y));
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

        Path path = getCurrentPath();

        if (dx>=TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy>=TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            path.quadTo(x,y,(x+mX)/2,(y+mY)/2);
            mX=x;
            mY=y;
        }
        invalidate();;
    }

    private void touchUp() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after many research and the following worked.
Just save the canvas layer after setting the background color and at last restore to count.
The onDraw method is as follows -

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBackground,0,0,null);

    int layerId = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);  // Line 1 added

    for (int i=0;i<historyPointer;i++) {
        Path path = paths.get(i);
        Paint paint = paints.get(i);

        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
    }

    canvas.restoreToCount(layerId); // Line 2 added
}
```